# *Really* turn off zsh autocorrect

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, autocorrect

I read all the tips on turning off zsh autocorrect for command completion. However, they are not working fully. I tried DISABLE_CORRECTION="true", unsetopt correct, unsetopt correct-all, unsetopt correctall etc. pp.
I don't want

```
rm .za<TAB>
```

to be corrected to

```
rm .adobe
```

, thank you very much :-)

Does anybody know how to turn it off for good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the control function `_approximate` is set in the completer style for zsh completion. Look if there is a line starting with

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer
```

in your zsh configuration. I may look something like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _approximate
```

Just remove `_approximate` and `zsh` will stop second-guessing you.

Comment: You did it. Now I can keep using zsh. :-)